# typename in dependent scope

Tags: c++, iterator, auto, typename, const-iterator

Below is a condensed version of my code that gives me a compiler error. The compiler tells me to put typename in front of 'std::deque::reverse_iterator', which makes sense. But if I do I receive the error at the bottom. What does it mean? How can it be resolved?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<class T>
class Stack{

    public:
        Stack(){}
        ~Stack(){}
        void push(T c) { s.push_back(c); }
        void inspect() const{
            for(typename std::deque<T>::reverse_iterator i=s.rbegin(); i!=s.rend(); i++)
                std::cout << *i << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        typename std::deque<T> s;
};


int main(){

  Stack<int> s;
  s.push(1);
  s.inspect();
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>::_Deque_iterator(std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*> >::iterator_type)'|
note: candidates are:|
note: std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::_Deque_iterator(const iterator&) [with _Tp = int; _Ref = int&; _Ptr = int*; std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>]|
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*> >::iterator_type {aka std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*>}' to 'const iterator& {aka const std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>&}'|
note: std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::_Deque_iterator() [with _Tp = int; _Ref = int&; _Ptr = int*]|
note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided|
note: std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::_Deque_iterator(_Tp*, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::_Map_pointer) [with _Tp = int; _Ref = int&; _Ptr = int*; std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::_Map_pointer = int**]|
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of where using `auto` would help you more than just saving typing. You're in a `const` member function, but trying to use your data member's `reverse_iterator`, not `const_reverse_iterator`.

Change `typename std::deque<T>::reverse_iterator` to `typename std::deque<T>::const_reverse_iterator`, or, more simply, `auto`.

This is in addition to the extra `typename` on your data member.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing dependent about `std::deque<T>`, so there mustn't be a `typename`. Only things to the right of a `::` where the left depends on a template parameter is dependent.